# WPF Events in Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, events, event-bubbling

I have an Winforms application that is using a WPF control (Avalon Edit if it matters) inside an ElementHost.

It seems to be working fine, but I would like to be able to handle KeyPress events of this control in the Winforms manner (without RoutedCommands and InputGestures), so I though I could just handle the Form's KeyDown event with KeyPreview set, but WPF events don't seem to bubble up to the Form.

So basically, how can you access a KeyDown event on a WPF control in the Winforms manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to add custom event handler for WpfControl itself, instead of trying to connect to WinForm's KeyDown.

Here's example. Let's say: your WinForm is of type `Form1`, WpfControl is `UserControl1`, and element host for WpfControl is called (won't ever guess)) - elementHost.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    elementHost.ChildChanged += ElementHost_ChildChanged;
}

private void ElementHost_ChildChanged(object sender, ChildChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctr = (elementHost.Child as UserControl1);
    if (ctr == null)
        return;
    ctr.KeyDown += ctr_KeyDown;
}

void ctr_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    /* your custom handling for key-presses */
}
```

UPD: `e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers` (e is `System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs`) stores info about Ctrl, Alt, etc.

Comment: The problem is that System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs doesn't actually expose the modifier keys, so you can't check for 'Ctrl+Z', only 'Z' or 'Ctrl'.

Even the Key property isn't a bitwise combination of modifier and key from what I've seen, it's just the main key pressed.

Comment: @Miguel, See update: e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers is what you need.

Comment: Oh, thanks for that, I would never have worked that out. Upvoted.

Comment: Good luck in WPF and WF mixing)